# This loop isn't working and the code needs improvement do you have any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, keypress

I'm pretty new to Python, and coding in general, and currently working with Python 3.5. I wanted to learn to automate things that need text boxes filled to run. I experimented with the code below in a video game just as a way to learn.

I would like it to substitute different item numbers that are in a list into the *consolecommand* text.

Thank you for your time.

The code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
from keyboard import press

keyboard = Controller()

def submit():
    press('enter')

def Keyboardpress1():
    keyboard.press('/')
    keyboard.release('/')

def waitone():
    time.sleep(1)

def consolecommand():
    keyboard.type("giveitem 172 49000")

def deepsix():
    time.sleep(6)

def main():
    deepsix()
    submit()
    waitone()
    Keyboardpress1()
    waitone()
    consolecommand()
    waitone()
    submit()
    deepsix()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, the code is designed to hit a number to activate the command console in game, then type a command. The pauses between typing/keyboard are because the code doesn't run smoothly without them.

Thanks, appreciate any help.

Edit: I implemented fixes I learned from suggested resource materials. Now my problems are much fewer. Thank you, people of the comments section.

Edit1: I implemented new code to fix a previous problem. Now to get the consolecommand to change numbers.

Comment: Connor Winter, Welcome!  I know you're learning so please do 2 things to your code:  1)  Indentation is critical to Python so please review code and make sure to edit to reflect proper indentation throughout.  2)  Please utilize user defined functions.  You have a block of code that repeats a zillion times and could benefit, to say the least, from a call to a user defined function.  You'll only need to supply different parameters in calling your function.  Always strive for DRY (don't repeat yourself) code.  So please address these items and resubmit.  Thank you.

Comment: @Scott , Thank you for your suggestions, you've been a big help.

Comment: You may consider posting this on code review stack exchange here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Connor Winter, hey!  Nice job!  I'll just add that you should further take advantage of parameterization.  Functions `Keyboardpress0()` and `Keyboardpress1()` are nearly identical and could be replaced by a single `Keyboardpress()` function that accepts a string (where even a single character is a string in Python, unlike some other languages that have a character type) that would then be used as the argument in the calls to `keyboard.press()` and `keyboard.release()` function. Again, always strive for DRY (don't repeat yourself) code.  It will make a bigger difference when your code grows...

Comment: @Scott I'm not exactly sure how to use strings. I have no background in other coding languages so I have no frame of reference. I'll look for some resource and come back. I resolved my "enter" problem however, so I actually don't need Keyboard.press('0') anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Connor Winterton, here's a very simplistic example of using a parameter to save repeating yourself.  Consider func1() that performs a simple calculation and prints a hard-coded message.  Consider func2() that is nearly the same except the message is different.  By passing a parameter into func3() you can write just one function that will perform the task of both to reduce your code and clutter, and give you the ability to pass in any other messages you may want in the future:

```
def func1():
    a = 1+2
    print(a,'hello')

def func2():
    a = 1+2
    print(a,'goodbye')

def func3(my_msg):
    a = 1+2
    print(a,my_msg)

# call the hardcoded functions
func1()
func2()

# call the new versatile function
func3('hello')
func3('goodbye')
func3('See you later!')
```